# Cannot import Pandasql in Python 2.7

Tags: python, pandasql

I've just installed a fresh version of Python 2.7.11 via [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and installed pandas 0.17.1 and pandasql 0.6.3.

Whenever I enter the python IDE and type:

```
import pandas
```

Or

```
import pandasql
```

I receive the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
import pandasql
File "/Users/kenkehoe/anaconda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandasql/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .sqldf import sqldf
File "/Users/kenkehoe/anaconda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandasql/sqldf.py", line 4, in <module>
from pandas.io.sql import to_sql, read_sql
ImportError: No module named io.sql
```

Everything seems dependent on this pandas.io.sql module. I've tried uninstalling Pandas and reinstalling and using pip instead of Anaconda, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas on how to successfully import pandasql?

Comment: have you tried doing it like in their own example: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandasql or https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/blob/master/examples/demo.py i.e. `import pandas as pd; from pandasql import sqldf` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your file is named `panda.py`, and that's what you actually import.

Comment: Ah that does seem to be the issue. I had a test file I named "pandas.py" that seems to be confusing the whole package. Renamed it and now it's working. Thanks!